# Saving segmented csv files after separating them by a column value

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science, business-intelligence

I'm trying to segment a csv file of names and emails. The file has first_name, last_name, email, and email domain. I need to classify them by 'business' or 'individual' email.

the data looks like this:
[CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/er4yD.png)

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Path\\to\\file\\5.csv")  

domains =['gmail.com',
'att.com',
'netzero.net',
'msn.com',
'yahoo.com',
'aol.com',
'bellsouth.net',
'hotmail.com',
'comcast.net',
'mail.com',
'verizon.net',
'ymail.com',
'live.com',
'netscape.net',
'icloud.com',
'cableone.net',
'alltel.net',
'worldnet.att.com',
'centurytel.net',
'earthlink.net',
'adelphia.com',
'alltell.net',]

individual = data.loc[data['Email-Domain'] == str(domains)]
business = data.loc[data['Email-Domain'] !== str(domains)]

print(individual[['First_Name_01','Last_Name_01','Email']])
print(business[['First_Name_01','Last_Name_01','Email']])
```

However when I run this script it just prints an empty list for the first output and then everything in the csv file one the next output.

Comment: ('First_Name_01','Last_Name_01','Email')

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are comparing a **list** of the **terminations** of the email (everything after the @) with **each whole emails**. You should look within the emails of the csv if their termination lays within the specified domains. Two things to correct: from the csv use only the email termination and not checking the equality (==) of a string with a list. Instead, check if each mail termination IS WITHIN the domains list.

You could do:

```
individual = data[data['Email-Domain'].str.split(“@”)[-1].isin(domains)]
business = data[~data['Email-Domain'].str.split(“@”)[-1].isin(domains)]
```

Comment: Actually, when I tested this out, I got it to work with "individual = data[data['Email-Domain'].isin(domains)]" and "business = data[~data['Email-Domain'].isin(domains)]" based upon the composition of your CSV sample data.  It didn't need the "str.split("@")" portion.

Comment: Perfect! I’m not quite sure how an email “john.doe@gmail.com” can be mapped to “gmail.com” without the split though, because it should compare the whole email address with the domains. But if it’s working I’m glad it works 

Comment: Seems @NoDakker solution works fine. The other solution keeps throwing back errors...